# Findall error to extract specific words from text in Python

Tags: python, list, function, findall

I've made a function to pick up some Latin words based on their features, e.g. words containing 'tion', 'ex', 'ph' or 'ost'. Case should be ignored.

```
import re 
def latin_ish_words(text): 
    latin = re.findall('tion|ex|ph|ost', text, re.I)
    return [list(latin)]
```

Results I was hoping for:

E.g., latin_ish_words("This works well") is []

E.g., latin_ish_words("This functions as expected")
is ["functions", "expected"]

However, my function is returning NoneType rather than the desired List. Any suggestions where I'm going wrong?

Comment: The only condition is that these tokens are contained within a word?

Answer (score 2):

This might be easiest without regex:

```
def latin_ish_words(text): 
    lats = {'tion', 'ex', 'ph', 'ost'}
    return [w for w in text.split() if any(lat in w.lower() for lat in lats)]
```

With regexes, the following would come close:

```
def latin_ish_words(text): 
    return re.findall(r'\b\w*(?:tion|ex|ph|ost)\w*\b', text, re.I)
```

`\b` is a word boundary
`\w` is an alpahanumeric char or underscore
`(?:...)` is a non-capturing groupy, otherwise `findall` would just produce the parenthesized groups.

Both implementations give you:

```
>>> latin_ish_words("This functions as expected")
['functions', 'expected']
```

Comment: Great - thanks for this! I'm still getting the following error: Any ideas?                                   Your result was in the wrong type
----------
- You returned type: NoneType
- Expected type: list

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example where using a regexp is the wrong solution. And I say that as someone who has been using regexps for four decades. Using Ipython 3.6:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: text = 'This functions as expected'

In [3]: latin = re.findall('tion|ex|ph|ost', text, re.I)

In [4]: latin
Out[4]: ['tion', 'ex']
```

The answer by @schwobaseggl is close to correct but does not appear to correctly handle word boundaries.

Comment: Thanks Kurtis. Apologies the question wasn't clear - I am actually looking to return the full words. E.g., latin_ish_words("This functions as expected")
    is ["functions", "expected"]. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: Yes, @user16759613, don't use a regexp. Split the string into words on whitespace then check the suffix of each word and accumulate the  matching words. This can be done using a regexp but that is more complicated, and in the case of Python's regexp engine, likely to be slower.